# TLScontact notified me that a final decision has been made on my visa application. Does it mean it was approved?

Tags: visas, uk, passports, application-status

I received an email from TLS contact requesting that I resubmit my passport, saying that the final decision has been made. I applied for a UK visa and chose the option to keep my passport. I wanted to know if this necessarily means that my application has been approved?

If I have to travel to another country to resubmit my passport, it would be pointless if the results are negative.

Comment: Hello , I am in a similar situation. From the time you submitted biometrics, how long it took to get this email ? Also have you submitted your passport ?

Answer (score 5):

> I wanted to know if it necessarily means my application is approved

No, this doesn't mean that your visa is approved, it can be either way, and you'll have to submit and wait for the passport to see the result of the application.

Visa decisions are confidential and delivered in sealed envelopes, nobody at the processing middleman (here TLScontact) know your application status, only the UK Home Office currently knows about your case

---

Relaying @Traveller, this is [what TLSContact says](https://pos.tlscontact.com/beirut_vac_pos_store_view/catalog/product/view/id/10/s/keep-my-passport-when-applying/):

> *Once the decision of your visa application has been made by the UK Visas and Immigration, you will be notified by email, and then you need to provide your passport to the Visa Application Centre (by post or in person). If you don’t provide your passport within the determined timeframe, your visa application will be refused; Once received, we aim to complete the application and return your passport as soon as possible*

Comment: Per https://pos.tlscontact.com/madrid_vac_pos_store_view/catalog/product/view/id/10/s/keep-my-passport-when-applying/category/4/ it’s possible to submit the passport by post *Once the decision of your visa application has been made by the UK Visas and Immigration, you will be notified by email, and then you need to provide your passport to the Visa Application Centre (by post or in person). If you don’t provide your passport within the determined timeframe, your visa application will be refused; Once received, we aim to complete the application and return your passport as soon as possible.*

Comment: @Traveller The fact that you can submit by post is extremely dependent on the country, not all countries/Visa services have that possibility

Comment: (+1) Yes, I didn’t have room in the comment to mention that :-)

Comment: @Traveller In hinesight, this doesn't seem to be a good idea if they need to go to another country to pick it up